# How to Share 1 JsonWebToken for 2 app to use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json-web-token

So I have a problem I have 2 application which are deployed on the same website with different ports, one is a **Login** application and one is a **HRIS System**.

My problem is that when my login app created the [token](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) and redirect to my hris system the hris app is still asking for credentials.

So I checked in the **web console->application->local storage** there's a `token` in my **login** app but when I go to the **HRIS** app its not there ?

**Login app web console**
[image]

**HRIS app web console**
[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same website with different ports means different applications and resource sharing between apps is strictly forbidden.

Well, there's a large discussion about sharing resource over different apps, but sharing credential is bad practice, you should try read OAuth for alternative strategy.

login > success > save to localstorage > redirect to HRIS.
I assume this is your current workflow? 
You can pass it as encrypted token as you redirecting to HRIS app. Decrypt it there and save it again to HRIS local storage.

Answer (score 1):

That's because browser's local storage is specific to one hostname and port, and isn't shared with others.

I see that you've it on some host and port number 85. So it won't even be shared with the same host on port number 82. That's how it works.